# Value not added while $http.post() using AngularJS consuming a Spring REST API

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, rest

I have a simple spring REST API as follow :

2 Entities (Product, Category)

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCat;
    private String nameCat;
    @OneToOne // I want is as a one to one relation
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
    // setters getters etc
}

@Entity
    public class Product implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long idProduct;
        private String nameProduct;
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product")
        private Category category;
        // setters getters etc
    }
```

I have 2 RestController :

Product :

```
@RestController
public class ProductRestService {

    @Autowired
    ProductBusiness productBusiness; // Spring DATA Repo

    @RequestMapping(value="/products", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Ferme addProduct(@RequestBody Product p) {
        return productBusiness.addProduct(p);
    }
}
```

Category :

```
@RestController
   public class CategoryRestService {

        @Autowired
        CategoryBusiness categoryBusiness; // Spring DATA Repo

        @RequestMapping(value="/categories", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Ferme addCategory(@RequestBody Category c) {
            return categoryBusiness.addCategory(c);
        }
    }
```

And here is my AngularJS code which consumes the REST API :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.product = null;
    $scope.addedProduct = null;
    $scope.category = {"product":$scope.addedProduct, "nameCat":null};

    $scope.saveProduct = function() {
        $http.post("/products", $scope.product)
             .then(function(response){
                 $scope.addedProduct = response.data;
             }, function(err){
                 console.log(err);
             });
    };

    $scope.saveCat = function() {
        $http.post("/categories", $scope.category)
             .then(function(response){
                 $scope.addedCategory = response.data;
             }, function(err){
                 console.log(err);
             });
    };
});
```

I call the methods `saveProduct()` and then `saveCategory()` by using a `ng-click` in an html file, the first method works and the value of the returned Product is saved in the `$scope.addedProduct`, then I click to save the Category it works too but the product doesn't get saved in the category even if i'm using `$scope.category = {"product":$scope.addedProduct, "nameCat":null};` then I pass the category object here `$http.post("/categories", $scope.category){..` which means that the previously addedProduct should be saved inside the `$scope.category` but it's not the case, a value NULL is added in the category table in the database instead of the actual `product_id` which I verified it exists in `$scope.addedProduct`. I don't know how to solve this. Sorry if it seems a bit unclear, and I can provide more info if needed.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT :

//

Comment: did you tried calling `$scope.$apply()` after you changed collection from response? See this ** [link](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)**

Comment: @ShankarGurav I get an error `[$rootScope:inprog]` while calling the $scope.$apply(), I think there is not need to call this while using `ng-click()` anyway.

Comment: Nothing will change property `product` after controller initially runs...will always be null

Comment: @charlietfl Oh this is exactly the problem, can please provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to put `$scope.category = {"product":$scope.addedProduct, "nameCat":null};` inside the `saveProduct` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `$scope.category = {"product":$scope.addedProduct, "nameCat":null};` as

`$scope.category = {product:$scope.addedProduct, "nameCat":null};`

and then instead updating `$scope.addedProduct = response.data;` update with
    `$scope.category.product = response.data;`

in your code addedProduct is nowhere backtracking where its assigned and its not going to work.

Comment: It doesn't help, I get an error because the `$scope.category` is null, so I cannot acces the product property, anyway I need the whole category object from the response and save it in the `$scope.category`. Now I understand the problem, the `$scope.category = {"product":$scope.addedProduct, "nameCat":null};` is not the same as the $scope.category here `$http.post("/categories", $scope.category)`, it's a scope problem that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: could you add [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) for example?